# Downloading images from URLs

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-2.x

I'm just beginning with Python and programming, so been trying to get as much experience reading code as possible.

The script mentioned below do grab images from URLs and put them in into a folder. The code is tested and works fine. Is there a way to shorten/improve this code? Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

```
import urllib2
from os.path import basename
from urlparse import urlsplit
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # for HTML parsing

global urlList
urlList = []

# recursively download images starting from the root URL
def downloadImages(url, level): # the root URL is level 0
    print url
    global urlList
    if url in urlList: # prevent using the same URL again
        return
    urlList.append(url)
    try:
        urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except:
        return

    soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(urlContent))
    # find and download all images
    imgTags = soup.findAll('img')
    for imgTag in imgTags:
        imgUrl = imgTag['src']
        try:
            imgData = urllib2.urlopen(imgUrl).read()
            fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
            output = open(fileName,'wb')
            output.write(imgData)
            output.close()
        except:
            pass

    # if there are links on the webpage then recursively repeat
    if level > 0:
        linkTags = soup.findAll('a')
        if len(linkTags) > 0:
            for linkTag in linkTags:
                try:
                    linkUrl = linkTag['href']
                    downloadImages(linkUrl, level - 1)
                except:
                    pass

# main
downloadImages('http://www.yahoo.com', 1)
```

Python version 2.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Notes about your code

- You can also simplify the way you look for the links to follow:

  ```
  for link in soup.select("a[href]"):
      downloadImages(link["href"], level - 1)
  ```

  Here, we are enforcing the `a` elements to have `href` values, not checking for elements to be found (since the loop body would just not be executed in this case).
- As far as managing the urls you've already visited:

  - *don't use globals*
  - use a `set` instead of a `list` for *faster lookups*
- It's also a good practice to always specify [the parser `BeautifulSoup` uses under-the-hood](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urlContent, "lxml")  
  # or soup = BeautifulSoup(urlContent, "html.parser")
  # or soup = BeautifulSoup(urlContent, "html5lib")
  ```
- follow [`PEP8` recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - specifically, naming is agreed to be in `lower_case_with_underscores` format, not `camelCase`
- no need to join the `urlContent` - simply pass `urlContent` to `BeautifulSoup`

#### Alternative solution

I would implement it this way:

```
try:
    from urlparse import urljoin
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.visited = set()
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36"}

        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()  # turn off SSL warnings

    def visit_url(self, url, level):
        print(url)
        if url in self.visited:
            return

        self.visited.add(url)

        content = self.session.get(url, verify=False).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

        for img in soup.select("img[src]"):
            image_url = img["src"]
            if not image_url.startswith(("data:image", "javascript")):
                self.download_image(urljoin(url, image_url))

        if level > 0:
            for link in soup.select("a[href]"):
                self.visit_url(urljoin(url, link["href"]), level - 1)

    def download_image(self, image_url):
        local_filename = image_url.split('/')[-1].split("?")[0]

        r = self.session.get(image_url, stream=True, verify=False)
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                f.write(chunk)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.visit_url('http://www.yahoo.com', 1)
```

Aside from things mentioned above, here are some other applied changes:

- using `requests` third-party library with a [shared session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)
- Python 2 and 3 compatible
- using class for sharing "session" and a set of visited urls
- separate methods to visit urls and download images
- [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) is used to avoid the code being executed on import
- changed the way image filename is determined (probably still not the best way)
- handling relative urls as well as absolute

Comment: Thanks for you answer, have you tested you code, it gives this error :         IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'p?c1=2&c2=7241469&c7=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&c5=2023538075&cv=2.0&cj=1'

Comment: @V_V I've added the `.split("?")[0]` to the image filename definition to get rid of http get parameters in the image url and filename - give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again :) . you code seems to be much faster. However it always gives error please for example try https://www.yahoo.com or https://www.hrp.org.uk.

Comment: What's the point of `if chunk:`? Is it really necessary to avoid writing nothing to the file?

Comment: @Rawing yeah, you are right, good finding! Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @V_V okay, I've applied couple fixes - had to ignore SSL errors, specify a User-Agent header and check for image urls to start with `http`. Works for me now. Check it out. NOTE: you probably want to handle relative image and link urls as well, right?

Comment: @alecxe yes i do :)

Comment: @V_V okay, updated the code to handle both absolute and relative urls. Works for me so far.

Comment: I get this error InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'javascript:void(0)'
when i search a webpage like https://www.google.com,

Comment: while saving image_url it get this error:  
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: even though some images are already parsed into the same folder  I think image_url returns an empty string, your file name is an empty string.

Comment: @V_V yeah, we need to probably skip "javascript" links - there is this `if not image_url.startswith(("data:image", "javascript")):` filter - please debug and see why it did not catch this url; and we also need improve on image name determination.

Answer (score 5):

## Catching exceptions

It's generally not a good idea to use `try`-`except` blocks when you aren't specifying what `Exception`s you want to catch, as you've done here:

> ```
> try:
>     urlContent = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
> except:
>     return
> ```

As well as here:

> ```
> try:
>     imgData = urllib2.urlopen(imgUrl).read()
>     fileName = basename(urlsplit(imgUrl)[2])
>     output = open(fileName,'wb')
>     output.write(imgData)
>     output.close()
> except:
>     pass
> ```

You should specify exactly which `Exception`s you are catching. If you don't, then every single `Exception` raised under the `try` block will be ignored, including ones caused by errors in *your* code. Ideally, you should also output to the user what exactly went wrong. Here's an example:

```
try:
    some_function(argument1, argument2)
except (ExceptionA, ExceptionB) as exception:
    print "X thing failed due to Y. Using Z instead may solve this"
```

## Opening files

In your code you open files using the standard `open` and `close` methods provided, like so:

> ```
> output = open(fileName,'wb')
> output.write(imgData)
> output.close()
> ```

While there's not much that's inherently wrong with doing this, it's almost always better (and safer) to use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) to open files. This means that the above code, using a context manager, would become this:

```
with open(fileName, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(imgData)
```

## Nitpicks

Other than the two things listed above, I really only have two other criticisms of your code, those two criticisms being purely stylistic in nature:

1. function names should be in `snake_case`, not `camelCase`
2. variable names should *also* be in `snake_case` and not `camelCase`

These two naming criticisms are documented in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official style guide for Python. I'd recommend taking a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `global` is generally discouraged and isn't needed in this example. You can leave out `global` and the code will function just fine.